# Using databound controls to obtain sum from column in related entity in Databound Gridview

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding, gridview, databound-controls

I have a gridview that is bound to a datasoure on page load. The datasource is connected to various other database tables, ie. `datasourceItem.relatedEntity`

There is a column in the gridview whose value is dependent upon the sum of a certain field in all related `relatedEntities`.

So `dataSourceItem` has a one to many relationship with `relatedEntity`, and I need to sum the value from a specific column in all related `relatedEntities`. I want to do this as simply as possible, and I know this syntax is wrong, but this is kind of what I wanted to do:

Markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sum">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("relatedEntity.ColumnName").Sum() %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind (databinding):

```
myGridview.DataSource = from ds in DataContext.dataSource
                        where ds.Id == selectId
                        select ds;
myGridview.DataBind();
```

I want to keep the amount of code to a minimum, so if this is at all possible, please help me figure out how. To be clear, the line of code I want to make work is this:

```
'<%# Bind("relatedEntity.ColumnName").Sum() %>'
```

Or at least something to that effect. I don't necessarily have to use the `Sum()` method... if there is a different/better way of handling this, feel free to let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use Eval instead of Bind.
Next, you need to cast the evaluated expression to your EntityCollection type

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text='<%# ((System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<relatedEntityItemType>)Eval("relatedEntity")).Sum(i=>i.ColumnName) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Also you need to the proper imports `<%@ Import Namespace="YourEntitiesNamespace" %>`
and System.Data.Entity

**Edit:**
If the page is doesn't compile, this is needed in web.config

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
     <assemblies>
     <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>            
      </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Also you can get rid off the full name of the type using the import directive

```
<%@ Import Namespace="..entities.." %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" %>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to want to work for me at all. The web.config already has the assembly added, I've imported the namespaces, but it doesn't want to databind. I'm getting an HttpException saying that *AnonymousType1b`8[...] doesn't contain property with the name relatedEntityItemType*

Comment: its a collection of `relatedEntities`, such that `relatedEntity.type = relatedEntity`

Comment: I think I see the problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, but would the fact that I'm getting an anonymous type have to do with how I'm databinding the gridview? Because of the formatting I need to do, I actually need to query the results of a query, and then databind to the second query, and I'm casting the first query AsEnumerable() in my 2nd query. ie. `myGridView.DataSource = from ds in firstQuery.AsEnumerable() select new { *properties* };`

Comment: No need. I figured it out, it was an issue with how EF likes to automatically make plural-names singular. Thank you so much!